# Closing questions as duplicates when the duplicate's accepted answer isn't ideal

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The following question:

[Using quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51183/2693)

was just closed as a duplicate of this question:

[Automatically convert quotations in the form of "abc" to become ``abc"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50712/2693)

But the accepted answer here uses the `quotes` package, whereas I think the best answer should be to use the `csquotes` package.  So by linking the closed question to the older question we encourage a less than ideal answer.

This doesn't seem like a very good thing.

Note that I'm concerned about the general issue of choosing duplicates, not just this specific instance.   The issue is that when we choose duplicates, should we take into consideration the validity of the accepted answer of the linked question.  Unlike the original acceptance (which we have no control over) linking to the duplicate is something we *do* have control over.

Answer (score 11):

The 'accepted' answer to a question is determined purely by the original questioner, while votes should (hopefully) show the best answer as determined by users as a whole. On the other hand, *questions* are duplicated if they cover the same material as a previous question. As such, it is always possible that the two questioners might feel that a different *answer* is the best for them. However, the model for the site is that we try to avoid duplicate questions, irrespective of whether they are answered or not.

I would say all the best here is to vote for what you feel is the best answer. Over time, that should mean that the best answers 'float to the top'.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But in this case wouldn't it make sense to close the older question and link to the newer one and let the more up-to-date answer on the new question end up being seen?  (In the case of the questions I linked to, the csquotes answer was lowest voted simply because it was added quite late.)

Comment: Possibly. I'd actually have duped both to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38985/replace-quotes-with-quotes (note: I have the leading anwer there!).